# How to support autoplay in IOS for chrome and safari using HTML5 audio tag?

Tags: html, audio

I am using HTML5 audio along with angular2. It works for desktop very smoothly. But when it comes to media device it seems not working.

I have tested on iOS chrome and safari.

Any help would be highly appreciated?

Comment: Please provide any code you try run otherwise it's hard to guess what's the issue.

Comment: @alljamin: Here is the plunker with source code.
https://plnkr.co/edit/eX5kVGXwP51Nf38uUS0G?p=preview